# Indeterminate JProgressBar animation lag

Tags: java, swing, debian, lag, jscrollbar

Using the following code

```
package scrollbartest;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ScrollBarTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JProgressBar b = new JProgressBar();
            b.setIndeterminate(true);
            b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 20));
            f.add(b);
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

the progressbar "indefinite" animation is very laggish. What am I doing wrong?

Some more information:

- OS: debian 9.8
- The code seems to work smoothly on other OS (tried on Windows)
- Happens both with oracle JDK 1.8.0_201 and OpenJDK 1.8.0_181
- Continuously moving the mouse cursor over the main JFrame lets the
  animation run smoothly
- The effect changes with selected look and feel: GTK+ is better than
  system default, but the effect is still there

Because of the fourth point, I think it is a sort of slow "refresh time"... can this be possible?

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE:**
Doing some research, I found out that the indeterminate progress bar animation can be controlled setting some parameters in the current look and feel:

```
ProgressBar.repaintInterval
ProgressBar.cycleTime
```

Unfortunately, some look and feels seems to ignore the first parameter, while some other seems not. For instance, MetalLookAndFeel seems to ignore it, resulting in laggish animation, with a repaint time of around 0.5 seconds, while NimbusLookAndFeel seems to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below line to enable video acceleration, if not enabled in your OS:

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
```

Comment: This seems to work. Unfortunately, it also breaks the rendering in a lot of other situations, showing black panels and controls... probably there is a reason why acceleration is disabled by default on this OS!